# Force parameter to be specific types that can be passed into a method

Tags: android, kotlin

```
Android 3.5
Kotlin 1.3
```

I have the following method that passes in a parameter that could be `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE`, or `GONE`

```
fun setPromotionVisibility(Int: toVisiblity) {
    tvPromoation.visibility = toVisibility
}
```

However, when I call this method I could pass in any Int that might not be a visibility i.e.

```
setPromotionVisibility(234)
```

instead of doing this:

```
setPromotionVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Just wondering if there anything I could do to force the user of the method to only enter `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE`, or `GONE`

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Strangely, this `IntDef` actually exists inside AOSP, but it's hidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a type-safe approach with an enum:

```
enum class Visibility(
    val asInt: Int
) {
    VISIBLE(View.VISIBLE),
    INVISIBLE(View.INVISIBLE),
    GONE(View.GONE),
}
```

which you then use as a parameter type:

```
fun setPromotionVisibility(toVisiblity: Visibility) {
    tvPromoation.visibility = toVisibility.asInt
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Annotation for this

```
@IntDef({View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Visibility {}

fun setPromotionVisibility(@Visibility toVisiblity: Int) {
tvPromoation.visibility = toVisibility
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the already defined interface from `android.view.View` ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is useful for your case, but in my projects, I almost never use `INVISIBLE`.

So, I made an extension function

```
fun View.visible(value: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

It also can be better:

```
fun View.visible(value: Boolean, animated: Boolean = false) {
    if (animated) {
        if (value) animate().alpha(1F).withStartAction { visibility = View.VISIBILE } 
        else animate().alpha(0F).withEndAction { visibility = View.GONE }
    } else visibility = if (value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```